# Erro ao compilar Android

Tags: java, android

Na hora de compilar, acontece o seguinte erro:

```
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED
Error:1 error; aborting
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code.
This is caused by library dependencies that have been compiled using Java 8 or above.
If you are using the 'java' gradle plugin in a library submodule add 
targetCompatibility = '1.7'
sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
to that submodule's build.gradle file.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
    //compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    targetCompatibility = '1.7'
    sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
}
```

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
   }

```
task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Pode mostrar o código onde ocorre o erro?

Comment: O erro informa como resolver: adicione `targetCompatibility = '1.7'`e `sourceCompatibility = '1.7'`ao *build.gradle*.

Comment: @ramaral Eu já atualizei a pergunta mostrando como esta meu `build.fgradle`.
Após adicionar ocorreu o seguinte erro `Error:(11, 0) No such property: targetCompatibility for class: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated
<a href="openFile:C:\Users\LordLokon\Desktop\Arquivos\Work Android\HorarioEscolaApp\build.gradle">Open File</a>`

Comment: Não é nesse gradle mas sim no do module e desta forma: `compileOptions {  sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7 targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7  }`. Mesmo assim não posso garantir que seja suficiente.

Comment: @ramaral Poderia me mandar o arquivo completo(para download ou escrito), por favor ??

Comment: O conteúdo do arquivo é diferente em cada projecto. Você tem de postar o seu para podermos tentar perceber onde está o problema.

Answer (score 1):

Alguma das dependências do seu projeto foi compilada com Java 8,mas você está usando Java 7 no projeto. Coloque seu projeto para usar Java 8 ou recompile a biblioteca que está causando o problema após fazer a alteração necessária.

Comment: Antes estava dando erro pro eu compilar em Java 8, por isso mudei para o 7.

Comment: Abra uma nova pergunta com o erro que tava dando antes, pois provavelmente não tem relação com essa pergunta/resposta.